# Why does a `multiprocessing` version take longer than a single process version in python 3 on Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to apply a function to a large `range` of numbers - and the version where I use a pool from `multiprocessing` takes much longer to finish than what I estimate for a "single process" version  -

Is this a problem with my code? Or Python? Or Linux?

The function that I am using is `is_solution` defined below-

```
as_ten_digit_string = lambda x: f"0000000000{x}"[-10:]

def sum_of_digits(nstr):
    return sum([int(_) for _ in list(nstr)])

def is_solution(x):
    return sum_of_digits(as_ten_digit_string(x)) == 10
```

When I run `is_solution` on a million numbers - it takes about 2 seconds

```
In [13]: %timeit [is_solution(x) for x in range(1_000_000)]                                                                                                        
1.9 s ± 18.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Based on this - for ~10 Billion numbers - it should take about 20,000 seconds or around 6 hours. But the `multiprocessing` version doesn't end even after 9 hours.

I am  using the multiprocessing module like this -

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(processes=24) as p:
    for solution in p.imap_unordered(is_solution, range(1_000_000_000, 9_999_999_999)):
        if solution:
            print(solution)
```

The python version I am using is `3.8` on linux.

I don't know if this is relevant - when I run the `top` command in linux - I see that when my main program has run for ~200 minutes - each of my worker processes has a CPU Time of about 20 minutes.

Comment: You can  just generate the list of all numbers which have sum of digits == 10, you don't need to test each sequential integer for that.

Comment: @Alex - I am curious how. Thanks. But more importantly, I wish to understand why my code behaves this way - I don't think my `is_solution` function is the reason for what I see, or is it?

Comment: How do you get the multiprocessing code to run?  No matter what I try, I just get "cannot pickle lambda" errors.  Both mac and ubuntu, python 3.8.

Comment: Sorry about that - I was using the lambda version of `is_solution` only for the ipython %timeit - in the multiprocessing script, that function is a normal `def` function. I have edited in my question above

Comment: @Mortz how many cores do you have? Each process above the number of cores reduces performance. Assuming those processes do cpu intensive tasks like yours. Also it may be that the actual time to send and receive data between processes is longer then the actual processing. To fix that you can send data in batches, not one by one. Meaning you can send [start, end] pair instead of single value to `imap_unordered` and fix your `is_solution` to accept a range.

Comment: @freakish - I have 4 processors.

Comment: @freakish - The multiprocessing `imap_unordered` accepts an optional `chunksize` parameter - I used that instead of modifying my `is_solution` function - when the chunksize=`1` (default) - then the time taken to run through a million numbers is ~35 seconds!!! When I change that chunksize to 40,000 - the time taken is < 1 second! Thank you

Comment: @Mortz great, perfect. Just remember to keep the number of workers around the number of cpus. 24 is way too much.

Comment: @freakish - could you please post your comment above as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiprocessing is not free. If you have X cpu cores then spawning more than X processes will eventually lead to performance degradation. If your processes do I/O then spawning even 10*X process may be ok. Because they don't strain cpu. However if your processes do calculations and memory manipulation then it might be that any process above X only degrades performance. In comments you've said that you have 4 cores, so you should set `Pool(processes=4)`. You may experiment with different values as well. Multiprocessing is hard, it may be that 5 or even 8 processes will still increase performance. But it is extremely likely that 24 processes over 4 cpu cores only hurts performance.

The other thing that you can do is to send data to subprocesses in batches. At the moment you send data one by one and since your calculation is fast (for a single datapoint) it may be that the interprocess communication dominates total execution time. This is a price that you do not pay in the single process scenario but you always pay when multiprocessing. To minimize its effect use `chunksize` parameter of `imap_unordered`.

Finally, try to reimplement your algorithm to avoid brute force. As suggested by @Alex.

Answer (score 1):

```
def solution(n, sum):
    """Generates numbers of n digits with the given total sum"""
    if n == 1 and sum < 10:
        yield str(sum)
        return
    if n < 1 or (sum > 9 and n < 2):
        return 
    if sum == 0:
        yield "0" * n
        return
    for digit in range(min(sum + 1,  10)):
        for s in solution(n - 1, sum - digit):
            yield str(digit) + s        

# Print all 4-digits numbers with total sum 10
for s in solution(4, 10):
    print(s)

# Print all 4-digits numbers with total sum 10, not starting with zero
for digit in range(1, 10):
    for s in solution(3, 10 - digit):
        print(str(digit) + s)
```

Comment: This is so cool - I timed it and this takes about 5 ms compared to 2 seconds for my brute force approach.

Comment: On my computer the solution for your original problem - 10 digit number - takes 0.1s